# DJANGO: Save two forms within one class-based view

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

I have difficulties saving 2 forms within one view the only first one is saving but I cant figure out how to save the second one. Here is my code and issue :

models.py

```
class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='officeAddress',blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Address(models.Model):
    address_line = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='District')
    province=ChainedForeignKey(Province,chained_field="country",chained_model_field=
     "country",show_all=False,auto_choose=True,sort=True)
    district=ChainedForeignKey(District,chained_field="province",
        chained_model_field="province",show_all=False,auto_choose=True,sort=True)
   
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Address"
        verbose_name_plural = "Addresses"
```

forms.py

```
class OfficeModelForm(BSModalModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Office
        fields = ['name']

class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['address_line','address_line2','country','province','district']
```

views.py

```
class OfficeCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    form_class = OfficeModelForm
    second_form_class =  AddressForm
    template_name = 'settings/create_office.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Office was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('company:office-list')    

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['address'] = self.second_form_class
        return context
```

create_office.html

```
{% load static i18n %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ address.media.js }}
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">{% render_field form.name  %}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{% render_field address.address_line %}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{% render_field address.address_line2 %}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{% render_field address.country %}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{% render_field address.province %}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{% render_field address.district %}</div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary ms-auto" type="submit">{% trans "Create new office" %}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I think I need first to save the address then use the address.id as a foreign key for office but I don't know how to do this in CBV.
Thanks for your help...

Comment: Why are you using foreign key instead of OneToOneField ? Does one office can contain multiple addresses ?

Comment: no, every office will contain only one address, will update it to use OneToOneField instead,

Answer (score 0):

You should change models base names. Example:

class OfficeCreateView(CreateView) instead class OfficeCreateView(BSModalCreateView)

or

class OfficeModelForm(form.ModelForm) instead class OfficeModelForm(BSModalModelForm)

Answer (score 0):

First, change the views to be a CreateView.
Then if your second form is still not submitting, override the post method of the CreateView. Like this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    address = self.second_form_class(request.POST, prefix='address')
    
    if form.is_valid() and address.is_valid():
        form.save()
        address.save()
        return redirect(self.request.path)
```

But change the redirect to whatever path you wish to go to.
I know this is a bit late but better late than never. If this fixed it, consider submitting this as the answer so people looking for a similar solution can see (: